# Git Extensions fails to fetch, git bash works

Tags: windows, git, git-extensions

I am having trouble fetching from a git server with GitExtensions. However, git bash works just fine.

In git extensions I have OpenSSH selected. However I do not authenticate to this server with SSH keys but with a user/password pair.

git bash uses the Credential Manager to store my passwords. If I delete my credentials from the Credential Manager and then try to fetch with Git Bash, a Windows pop-up window will come up and ask for credentials and the fetch will work.

If I try to fetch within the Git Extensions GUI, no pop window comes and I get a time-out error.

How can I get GitExtensions to use the credentials stored in the Credential Manager, or how can I get it to ask me for my credentials when I fetch?

Comment: You're more likely get a better help at https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues.
What is wrong and how to get it fixed could depend on many factors, including but not limited to git version, Git Extensions version, SSH configurations etc.
You can check settings under Git Extensions > SSH and Git > Paths.